# jQuery sortable() - How to check if two <li> elements are next to each other by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am developing a display builder for outdoor power equipment dealers, in which they can add, remove, and rearrange product display sections as they see fit. I used a `<ul>` with JQuery-ui `sortable()` to do this:

This is the sortable `<ul>`, called `#display-sections`

```
<ul id="display-sections">
</ul>
```

When a button is pressed to add a section(blower, chainsaw, hedge trimmer, trimmer, accessories, PAS, cordless), a `<li>` is appended with the appropriate class.

For example, if I click on the button to add a blower section, a `<li>` is added with the class `echo-blower-section`:

```
function addBlowerSection() {
  $("#display-sections").append('<li class = "echo-blower-section"><img src = "echo-blower-section.jpg" width = "145" height = "288"></li>');
}
```

**There are two display sections, the PAS and Cordless Sections, classes `echo-pas-section` and `echo-cordless-section` that I want to check if they are NOT next to each other, since it is recommended that these two sections stay together in a showroom.**

How would I do this using JavaScript/JQuery? I would like to present an alert if the `echo-pas-section` and `echo-cordless-section` list items are NOT next to each other in the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested, but I think something like this should do the trick :-)

```
var cordless = $("#display-sections li.echo-cordless-section");
var pas = $("#display-sections li.echo-pas-section");

if(cordless.length && pas.length && !cordless.next('li').is(pas) && !pas.next('li').is(cordless)){
    alert('!');
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. I placed this code in the sortable stop() function, so it checks every time the items have been dragged and dropped.